# Download PDF from node API via FTP

Tags: node.js, ftp, polymer, polymer-2.x

I have PDF on a remote server. I have API with node and I want, from my website, download the PDF.

I'm using `jsftp` to upload and read PDF. It works fine :

```
let str = '';
FTP.get('path/to/my/file', (err, socket) => {
    socket.on("data", d => {
        str += d.toString();
    });
    socket.on("close", err => {
        if (err) {
            console.error("There was an error retrieving the file.", err);
        }
        // HERE I HAVE THE FILE IN STRING
    });
    socket.resume();
});
```

On the close event I have the file in String, but I don't succeed to send it to the browser. I've tried things like :

```
let s = new Readable();
s.push(str);
s.push(null);
s.pipe(res);
```

OR

```
res.end(str);
```

But nothing happen in browser

I'm using Polymer for my ajax request

```
<iron-ajax
    id="openPdf"
    content-type="application/json"
    method="POST"
    url="/api/karaweb/pdf"
    on-response="handleOpenPdfResponse"
    on-error="errorMessage"></webservice-request>
```

Any solutions ?

Thanks

Comment: [Have you tried `socket.write()`?](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_socket_write_data_encoding_callback) Before the `socket` is `closed`.

Comment: I'v got this error `This socket has been ended by the other party
` in `socket.on('end')` when I try `socket.write`

Comment: You can only write to an `open` `socket`. Can you — not — send in `.on('data'…)`?

Comment: Nothing is happening to ...

Comment: I can't help you on the socket, but in your `iron-ajax`, `content-type="application/json"` says you expect JSON, not a PDF. I believe you need to remove that, and add `handle-as="blob"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a mixin called `PdfDownloaderMixin`; here is the whole code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">

<dom-template id="pdf-downloader-mixin">
    <script>
        /* @polymerMixin */
        const PdfDownloaderMixin = (superClass) => class extends superClass {
            constructor() {
                super();
            }

            downloadPdf(blobData) {
                let fileObjectUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blobData);
                window.open(fileObjectUrl);
            }
        }
    </script>
</dom-template>
```

Then you use like this in your element:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer-element.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html" />
<link rel="import" href="pdf-downloader-mixin.html" />

<dom-module id="attachment-handler">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax id="getAttachmentAjax"
                   url="[[rootPath]]api/session/getattachment"
                   debounce-duration="300"
                   handle-as="blob"></iron-ajax>
    </template>
    <script>
        class AttachmentHandler extends PdfDownloaderMixin(Polymer.Element) {
            static get is() { return 'attachment-handler'; }

            getAttachment() {
                this.$.getAttachmentAjax.generateRequest().completes.then((req) => {
                        req.succeeded && this.downloadPdf(req.response);
                    });
            }
        }

        customElements.define(AttachmentHandler.is, AttachmentHandler);
    </script>
</dom-module>
```